Conditions for Pointwise convergence to imply uniform convergence
I have the following situation. Let $f:\mathbb{R}^p \times \Theta \to \mathbb{R}$ a measurable function. Moreover, let $X_n$ be a sequence of real-valued random vectors. I know that the function converges pointwise in probability
$$
f(X_n, \theta) \stackrel{p}{\longrightarrow} g(\theta) \qquad \forall\theta\in\Theta
$$
Under which conditions can I claim that the convergence holds for:
$$
\sup_{\theta\in\Theta}f(X_n, \theta) \stackrel{p}{\longrightarrow} \sup_{\theta\in\Theta} g(\theta)
$$
I would be grateful for any help.

Do you want uniform convergence or is convergence of the suprema (which is strictly weaker) enough?

@ThomasLumley thanks for your comment. I'm interested in uniform convergence, i.e., $\sup_{\theta\in\Theta}\vert f(X_n, \theta) - g(\theta)\vert \stackrel{p}{\longrightarrow} 0 $

Why not use equicontinuity?

Ok, so you need stochastic equicontinuity of $f$ and probably compactness of $\Theta$.
A useful reference is: Newey's 1989 research report Uniform convergence and stochastic equicontinuity (PDF)
A sufficient condition on top of compact $\Theta$ and pointwise convergence is a stochastic Lipschitz condition: there exists a sequence of real random variables $B_n$ such that
$$\|f(X_n,\theta_1)-f(X_n,\theta_0)\|\leq B_n d(\theta_1,\theta_2)$$
and $B_n=O_p(1)$, where $d$ is a metric on $\Theta$. This is corollary 2.1 in the report.
This is the stochastic version of the real-analysis result that pointwise convergence plus equicontinuity gives uniform convergence.

Thanks @ThomasLumley, that helps a lot! Just out of curiosity, what would have been the needed assumptions if instead I only require converges of the supermum?

I'd have to look them up, but that's Wald's method for consistency.   The other note I wanted to make is that the main way to get even weaker conditions is for $f(X_n,\theta)$ to actually be a mean.
